# When we change the value of A[i][j], do we need the load the entire array of A[i]?

Tags: arrays, virtual-memory

Or does the system only need to load A[i] into the virtual memory to change the value of A[i][j]?

Comment: depends a lot on the language you are using, how you are loading (by value or reference) etc etc etc. wheres the code?

Comment: What do you mean by "load the entire array"? Generally arrays are in memory all the time (they're not backed by disk based storage or anything), so nothing really gets loaded at any point in accessing `A[i][j]`. I guess you could count that two pointers get dereferenced (`(A+i)` and `(*(A+i)+j)`).

Comment: Well, virtual memory pages can be swapped to the harddisk. however, this should only be relevant for very large arrays (large in terms of memory space).

Answer (score 1):

In most cases this will not be necessary. However, as virtual memory operations are performed on page level, the system will load at least one page.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are generally allocated as a contiguous block of memory with a fixed size per element. The array variable points to the first location in that block of memory. When you specify an index, the array accessor will jump that many blocks of memory and that's how it can quickly access elements by index. An array is passed by reference (which is the pointer to the first memory location).